# appending dicts based on keys- overwriting previous values

Tags: python

In python 3.8, I have the following dict:

```
dict_base= dict()
```

Then I am generating another dict in my operation

```
dict_1={'Sedan': 'Accord',
        'SUV': 'Pilot'
        }

dict_base.append(dict1)
```

This appends dict1 to dict_base.
Next I have a second dict

```
dict_2={'Sedan': 'Camry',
        'SUV': 'Highlander'
       }

dict_base.append(dict_2)
```

What I am expecting is to see a result as follows:

```
dict_base={'Sedan': ['Accord', 'Camry'],
           'SUV': ['Pilot', 'Highlander']
           }
```

What I am seeing is

```
dict_base={'Sedan':'Camry',
            'SUV':'Highlander'
          }
```

So, I am not sure how to append correctly...as it appears my append operation is overwriting the previous values.
Thanks!

Comment: `dict_base.append(dict1)` will cause an error, not show that output, since dictionaries don't have a `append` method. I think you're missing `[]` in there to do a lookup, but the code should work after that.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a good usecase for `collections.defaultdict`. You can't magically append each value of one dict containing strings to the corresponding keys of a dict containing lists. Python has no idea what you want to do, so you have to spell it out.

Make a dictionary that defaults to lists for missing elements:

```
dict_base = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

For each element of `dict_1`, `dict_2`, etc, tell python what to do with the values:

```
for k, v in dict_1.items():
    dict_base[k].append(v)
```

Do the same thing for `dict_2`, or better yet, write a function:

```
def append_base(base, d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        base[k].append(v)
```

You can also do this with conventional dictionaries, especially if you know the list of keys ahead of time:

```
keys = ['Sedan', 'SUV']
dict_base = {k: [] for k in keys}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
dict_1 = {'Sedan': 'Accord', 'SUV': 'Pilot'}
dict_2 = {'Sedan': 'Camry', 'SUV': 'Highlander'}
```

You can use `itertools` with `collections`:

```py
import itertools
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in itertools.chain(dict_1.items(), dict_2.items()):
    result[key].append(value)
    
print(dict(result))
# Outputs {'Sedan': ['Accord', 'Camry'], 'SUV': ['Pilot', 'Highlander']}
```

You can use `collections`:

```py
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in (dict_1, dict_2):
    for key, value in d.items():
        result[key].append(value)
    
print(dict(result))
# Outputs {'Sedan': ['Accord', 'Camry'], 'SUV': ['Pilot', 'Highlander']}
```

Hell, you can even use nothing:

```
result = {}
for d in (dict_1, dict_2):
    for key, value in d.items():
        result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
        
print(result)
# Outputs {'Sedan': ['Accord', 'Camry'], 'SUV': ['Pilot', 'Highlander']}
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds. Nice. Very similar answers :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Nice answer too, mate! +1

Comment: Thanks folks...wonderful solutions and explanations! As a quick followup, if each item of my dict is a pandas df, that I am appending to, then would I initialize as ````dict_base = collections.defaultdict(pd.DataFrame)````?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining dict_base as dict, you can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

It can be this way -

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_1={'Sedan': 'Accord',
        'SUV': 'Pilot'
        }
dict_2={'Sedan': 'Camry',
        'SUV': 'Highlander'
       }

dict_base = defaultdict(list)
    for d in (dict_1, dict_2):
       for key, value in d.items():
         dict_base[key].append(value)
```